# How to get the call paths to a given function?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm using Eclipse to debug a Java app.

I'd like to see all the possible "call paths" leading to calls to a specific function `somefunc`.

Does Eclipse provide a way to get this information?  (FWIW, I'm using Juno Service Release 1; Build id: 20121004-1855.)

PS: FWIW, at least some calls to `somefunc` result from choices made by the user interactively, so I expect that some of the call paths will start in one or another GUI event handler.

EDIT: this is what I mean by a "call path".  Suppose that some event handler `a` calls function `b`, then `b` calls `c`, `c` calls `d`, and finally `d` calls `somefunc`.  Then the sequence

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> somefunction
```

is one of the call paths I'm interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does 'right click' >> Open Call Hierarchy help?

It does not aggregate all direct and indirect callers in a flat structure, but gives you a tree through.

Answer (score 1):

Left click in the method name, then right click -> References -> Project (or Workspace)

This will show you all the places that that method is called from.  I am not sure if that is what you mean by "call path" or not.

Comment: No, sorry, this is not what I meant.  See my clarification above.