# How to get list of all the call paths that call a method?

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

I'd like to see all the possible "call paths" leading to calls to a specific method `somefunc`.

Does Visual Studio provide a way to get this information?

PS: FWIW, at least some calls to `somefunc` result from choices made by the user interactively, so I expect that some of the call paths will start in one or another GUI event handler.

By a "call path" I mean.  Suppose that some event handler `a` calls function `b`, then `b` calls `c`, `c` calls `d`, and finally `d` calls `somefunc`.  Then the sequence

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> somefunction
```

and also g -> e -> somefunction

then We get

1.)a -> b -> c -> d -> somefunction

2.)g -> e -> somefunction

.

.

.

etc.

PS : this question is very simiar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753857/how-to-get-the-call-paths-to-a-given-function) but instead of Eclipse we are using Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

If you're satisfied with the answer given in the Eclipse question you linked, you should be able to get similar results in Visual Studio by right-clicking on a method and selecting *View Call Hierarchy* from the context menu or by hitting **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>** and then **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>** when the text cursor is on said method.

Comment: That only shows one caller at a time! Not all the callers and the paths leading to them.

Comment: From what I can tell, the output is not all that dissimilar from the accepted answer in the Eclipse question in that it shows call paths in a tree view. If you need the output in a flat structure then I suspect you're going to need an extension to do that for you.

Comment: Maybe you have a different view, in my view I only see the immediate callers only, do you see the caller of callers and their callers all the way to top of the graph?

Comment: Aaaah! That starts from main and goes to method 3! Try starting from method 3 and going all the way back to main method, Also have another method that calls method 3 then you should see both of the paths that end with method 3.

Comment: [Like this?](http://i.imgur.com/3PHEQzX.png) Depending on your perspective you could certainly argue it's a little messy given the way that callers and callees are split into child nodes, but it seems to get the job done, for the most part.

Comment: I think I saw something nice when I was trialling NDepend, but I cant remember. Using View Call Hierarchy like this is not option in  real projects.